# Table of contents: Page numbering for questions and solutions side-by-side?

Tags: table-of-contents

The book "One thousand exercises in probability" (Grimmett, Stirzaker) has a very nice table of contents: [image]

As it looks like, the book only consists of chapters: First, all exercise chapters (including sections) appear, then the corresponding solutions (with the same chapter/section structure). I reset the chapter numbering (see below) to reflect that, but how can one create a table of contents as shown above?

Here is a basic template:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\section{Section 3}
\clearpage
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\chapter{Solutions to Chapter 1}
\section{Solutions to Section 1}
\section{Solutions to Section 2}
\section{Solutions to Section 3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132901/4686, see this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133559/4686 (which possibly might be improved upon, package `etoc` has evolved since)

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. I had a quick look at it and it looks good, but I think it addresses a different problem (namely how to produce a split toc *after* a standard toc). In that sense, I didn't immediately see how this might be helpful here, but if you see how, please post a solution (based on `etoc`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, there is a problem with the QStar's suggested solution. Since I didn't hear back from him, I opened another question. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270623/table-of-contents-chapters-side-by-side-in-toc/271035#271035) and more so [here](http://www.komascript.de/node/1971) (in German) for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

A bit hacky, but it gives the desirable result... Currently, it's still required to manually add the label per each solution section. It would be desirable if this also could be automated.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{titletoc}

% {section}, [left], {above}, {before with label}, {before wo label},
% {filler and page}, [after]
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.5em]{\addvspace{1pc}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{1.2em}}{}
    {\hfill\contentspage\hspace{5.2em}\pageref{\thecontentslabel}\hspace*{-1.4em}}
\titlecontents{section}[4em]{\addvspace{0.1pc}}{\contentslabel{2.5em}}{}
    {\hfill\contentspage\hspace{6.1em}\hyperlink{\thecontentslabel}{\pageref{\thecontentslabel}}\hspace*{-1.6em}}
\newcommand{\sectionsol}[2]{\hypertarget{#2}{\section{#1}\label{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\hfill Questions\hspace{1em}Solutions\par}

% Exercises
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\section{Section 3}

% Solutions
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}% removes all toc entries of after this line
\chapter{Solutions to Chapter 1}\label{1}
\sectionsol{Solutions to Section 1}{1.1}
\sectionsol{Solutions to Section 2}{1.2}
\sectionsol{Solutions to Section 3}{1.3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}% display contents (down to subsections) in toc again

\end{document}
```

[image]

Removes all table of contents entries of any level from this line. You'll have to change this behavior back if you want for example appendices to appear in the toc after this line.

Overall, the idea is to redefine the format of the table of contents. Add manually a cross-reference to the section label. And manually add the label. There is most certainly a more gracious way of doing this, though.

Edit: Added a manual fix for the `hyperref` package. Manually a `hypertarget` is added by the new defined `\sectionsol` command, which defines both the target and a label. Finally, a `hyperlink` is added in the toc, which points to the hypertarget.

Edit: Copied over the adjusted solution by Marius Hofert, which has better spacing. And to save it in case a better solution comes along.

When using the `mathtools` package the `\setcounter` macro has to be protected. [See this answer for more details.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65029/problems-with-mathtools-package)

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. I also get the solution pages first from the code. Also, do you know how to get the titles "Questions" and "Solutions" (otherwise the reader doesn't recognize which is which)?

Comment: The manual `\section` labels might become tedious

Comment: I plan to link to the chapters/sections anyways, so they will have labels. More important would be to have 'labels' for the two columns of page numbers in the toc.

Comment: I changed the answer to create something, which looks okayish.

Comment: If `hyperref` is used, the links will go wrong -- this is due to the counter resetting of `chapter` for the solution chapter

Comment: How about this manual fix? By manually adding a hypertarget on the section title and a hyperlink on the solution page number. That fixes the problem.

Comment: @QStar: It might work, but I can't test right now. Perhaps you need `\phantomsection` before each label

Comment: Well I tested it and it works at least at my end. I didn't had to use `\phantomsection`.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I provided an update with slightly nicer spacings etc. Feel free to take it and update your answer. I'll still leave it open for a bit, maybe someone comes up with a more elegant solution which does not require the labels being 1.1, 1.2... etc.

Comment: @QStar If you add `\usepackage{mathtools}`, pdflatex fails with `Undefined control sequence.` It doesn't like the `\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}` it seems. Do you know a solution for that?

Comment: You'll have to change the `\addtocontents` line to `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}`. For an explanation, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65029/problems-with-mathtools-package

Comment: @QStar Something else I realized: If there are chapters (like 'preface') which only have a single page number, the toc still shows the 'two-column layout'. Is there an easy way to switch the 'two-column layout' on/off? You can see this by adding `\addchap{Preface}` before the line starting with `\addtocontents{toc}{\hfill Questions...` in the example. It would be great if "Preface" would appear with its page number aligned with those of the solutions, then some vertical space, and then the 'two-column layout'.

Comment: ... and the same with `\printbibliography`... the page number appears in the left column and the right columns shows `??`.

Comment: Okay, I managed to do it. I use `\chapter*{Preface}\label{chap:pref}`  and then `\addtocontents{toc}{{\bfseries Preface\hfill\pageref{chap:pref}}\par}`. Similarly for the bibliography and index... just avoid having them being included in the toc (and thus being printed in 'two-column format') and then add them by hand via `\addtocontents{toc}{...}`

Comment: @QStar: I just realized that if your solutions appear on a page with page number having more than 1 digit, then the `\hspace{5.2em}` creates a fixed space between the page numbers for questions and solutions and that the page numbers for the questions are 'pushed further to the left'. Any idea how to avoid this? I tried to use a `tabular` environment but it didn't work (it might still be a good approach, though)