# Table of contents: Chapters side-by-side in toc

Tags: table-of-contents

The following code is adapted from
[here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267045/table-of-contents-page-numbering-for-questions-and-solutions-side-by-side)
The idea is to create a book with two parts (containing problems and solutions)
which have equal (numbered) chapter and (unnumbered) section headings. In order
to keep the toc small, the page numbers for both parts should appear
side-by-side in the toc (due to the very similar structure in both
parts). Furthermore, the sections (although not numbered) should appear in the
toc and the page heads. Here are the problems left based on the MWE below:

- The page number for solution sections don't appear in the toc (only '??'
  appear)
- The page numbers of chapters and sections don't seem to be (vertically)
  aligned correctly, especially in the case where some solutions are on a page >= 100
  (3-digits). This certainly comes from the `\hspace` between the page
  numbers of problems and their solutions in `\titlecontents` below.
  (It seems that a table-like toc would be the way to go to ensure
  right-alignment of the page numbers, but I didn't manage to get this to work).

How can these two issues be fixed?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% TOC
% {section}, [left], {above}, {before with label (left side)}, {before wo label
% (left side)}, {filler and page}, [after]
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.9em]{\addvspace{1pc}\sffamily\bfseries}{\contentslabel{1.7em}}{}
    {\hfill\contentspage\hspace{5.4em}\pageref{\thecontentslabel}\hspace*{-1.4em}}
\titlecontents{section}[2em]{\addvspace{0.1pc}}{\contentslabel{2.5em}}{}
    {\hfill\contentspage\hspace{6.02em}\hyperlink{\thecontentslabel}{\pageref{\thecontentslabel}}\hspace*{-1.5em}}
\newcommand{\addsecsol}[2]{\hypertarget{#2}{\addsec{#1}\label{#2}}}% define solution section, which is shown in toc

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1em}\hfill Problems\hspace*{1.4em}Solutions\par}% header for toc
\tableofcontents% without number; add bookmark on level 0
\chapter{Chapter A problems}\label{chap:1}
\addsec{Section 1}
\lipsum[1-100]
\addsec{Section 2}
\lipsum[101-200]

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}% remove toc entries after this line
\chapter{Chapter A solutions}\label{2}
\addsecsol{Section 1}{2.1}
\lipsum[201-300]
\addsecsol{Section 2}{2.2}
\lipsum[301-400]
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}% display contents (down to subsections) in toc again
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why using `titletoc` with a KOMA class?

Comment: Because of the `\titlecontents` commands (?)

Comment: Well, of course. My comment was meant to indicate that `titletoc` might not be fully compatible with KOMA classes (`titlesec` is not). With KOMA classes, I think,  one should use `tocstyle` (from the same author of the classes).

Comment: This is also discussed on the KOMA-Script website, see http://www.komascript.de/node/1971

Comment: yes, that was me -- I decided to post it there as well, as I know Markus Kohm a bit but am not sure whether he reads tex.stackexchange. Of course I provide a full solution once it's working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this problem is quite KOMA-script-specific (and since I didn't receive an answer by then), I also posted it in the [komascript forum](http://www.komascript.de/node/1971). Markus Kohm came up with a beautiful solution (thanks a ton, Markus!); see Markus' answer there for the details.